# OutofRangeException when binding dropdownlist with selected value having &(ampersand)

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, special-characters, data-binding

The exception says my dropdown "has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items"

This is after selecting the item from a previous page.  The dropdown is bound to a dataset filled with data from a stored procedure.  The value from the database has an ampersand in it which is encoded in the html source.  When I remove the ampersand from the data it doesn't throw the exception anymore.  I think its because it can't match the posted value to the encoded html but I'm not sure how the binding works.

Comment: Are you using HTMLEncode to save the vale with the & to the database?

Comment: I'm not sure if its encoded but the & is in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in saving the dropdown value directly to the object before redirecting to the next page.  I was saving the Encoded value and needed to save the Decoded value.  I called Server.HtmlDecode when saving it and it no longer throws the exception.